# Java regex not respecting the specified quantifier

Tags: java, regex

I have the following line from a CSV file:

`Name,Age,Country,State,Zip,Phone,Email,Address`

I am using the following Java `regex` to capture `Name,Age,Country` into 1 group but it always captures this:

Regex --> `^((?:.*,){3})`

Result --> `Name,Age,Country,State,Zip,Phone,Email,`

Why is it not respecting the `{3}` quantifier I am using?

Comment: Because `.` matches all characters and `*` is greedy.

Comment: What happens when you add a question mark directly after the *, like this: `.*?`

Comment: You cannot extract separate groups with `{3}` anyway. You will need `^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)`

Comment: I've seen it's closed as duplicate, and I won't reopen it, but the linked question has quite bad answers, have a look at the one here. Explicit matching should always be preferred to just the non greedy solution.

Comment: @anubhava or simply use `[^,]+` instead and forget about capture groups altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dot matches a comma too. You have two solutions:

- the bad one, make it not greedy: `^((?:.*?,){3})`
- the right one: exclude commas: `^((?:[^,]*,){3})`

The first one is bad because it's expensive and has potential for catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: I guess you could also use ^((?:\w+,){3}) so it just captures words.

Comment: @PeterS but what if there's several words between two commas ?

Comment: @PeterS as Denys mentioned. Especially considering these will likely be actual names, countries, states, zips, etc. each of which can have spaces.